# VisualSVN and Eclipse

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, subversive

I have installed VisualSVN on a Windows Server 2008 machine. Do I have to change the firewall settings and how?

By the way, it is possible to use the Subversive plugin to connect to it? I have installed Subversive plugin and connector.

When I input the repository location, it always give me an error message. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Specify repository location]

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you entered wrong URL to repository. The URL should be `https://192.168.8.88/svn/repos`

Of course you have to create repository in VisualSVN Server Manager before connecting from Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, I should append the repo name, then it is fixed